# Solr schema strategy

Tags: solr

We are creating an entertainment site which we want to be able to search events, restaurants & bars, movies, arts & theater, and TV/radio.

All of these obviously have different fields associated with them.

A restaurant would have the following fields: name, address, category, description

A movie would have the following fields: name, theater_name, theater_address, times, description

arts & theater: name, address, venue_name

Should I be storing all of these in the same index? How would you recommend sharing common fields and creating unique fields for each content type?

Sometimes this would be searched individually while other times they might be searched together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is are posts about some of the tradeoffs between a single index and multiple indexes.

- [Solr Combined Versus Single Index](http://khaidoan.wikidot.com/solr-combined-versus-single-index)
- [Multiple Indexes](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MultipleIndexes)
- [Multiple Doc Types](http://searchhub.org/dev/2011/02/12/solr-powered-isfdb-part-4/)

Based on what you have shown for fields, I would suggest using common fields for `name, address, description` and then additional specific fields for each type as necessary. In regard to the additional fields, you could leverage the power of [Dynamic Fields](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Dynamic_fields) if you do not want to define all of the additional fields up front.

```
 <dynamicField name="theater_*" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```